# Routing in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm learning angular 2 but is facing a problem which is a tad confusing to me. If I have a `core` and a `nav` component, and I want the `nav` component to render a route defined in the `core` component, how do I do that?

Because now I've defined the routes in my `core` component and put a `[routerLink]="['About']"` attribute in my `nav` component template, but it seems as if it can't find it or that some error occurs because as soon as I add this attribute directive it causes the core component to not load as well as semi-freezing the browser, as if it's performing some sort of infinite loop.

I get no errors telling me anything which doesn't help me a bit. I've read the documentation for routing in angular2 but they only show it with a single component, not when trying to load routes defined in the `core` component from a separate component. What could be the issue here?

**core.component.ts**:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
import {NavComponent} from '../nav/nav.component';
import {AboutComponent} from '../about/about.component';
import {ContactComponent} from '../contact/contact.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'core-app',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/core/core.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/core/core.component.css'],
  directives: [NavComponent]
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '...', name: 'Home', component: CoreComponent},
  {path: '/about', name: 'About', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: '/contact', name: 'Contact', component: ContactComponent}
])

export class CoreComponent {

}
```

**nav.component.ts**:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {NavService} from '../nav/nav-api.service';
import {NAVLIST} from '../nav/nav-list';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-list',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/nav/nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/nav/nav.component.css'],
  providers: [NavService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  host: {
    '(mouseenter)': 'show()',
    '(mouseleave)': 'hide()'
  }
})

export class NavComponent {
  public isToggled = false;
  public links = NAVLIST;

  constructor(private _navService: NavService) {}

  show() {
    this.isToggled = this._navService.show();
  }

  hide() {
    this.isToggled = this._navService.hide();
  }
}
```

**nav.component.html**:

```
<nav class="nav-wrapper" [class.is-toggled]="isToggled" [class.is-hidden]="!isToggled">
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li class="nav-link" *ngFor="#link of links">
      <a [routerLink]="['About']">
        <div class="label-wrapper">{{link.label}}</div>
        <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="{{link.icon}}"></i></div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Maybe because you have the routeLink inside of a ngFor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: `{path: '...', name: 'Home', component: CoreComponent},`

By doing `'...'` you are saying that some other component will solve the path (that component needs RouteConfig on it) you want the `CoreComponent` to handle all routes, but all routes already go through it. So you are redirecting to it indefinitely.

Comment: Hmm, that did solve it. But what if a child component have it's own routes, such as "new", "edit" and "list", how would that affect things? Because then I don't want to write these routes inside the core component. Will other components be able to find these routes defined outside of the core component?

Comment: Also I don't understand how to send the user back to the core component if I'm not allowed to set a route for it inside of the routeConfig. Perhaps the core component should never be its own view but rather just handle all of its children?

Comment: So, any component that has `@RouteConfig` on it its called a Routing Component, there can only be one "Root Routing Component" and that must be the one you bootstrap, in this case I'm guessing its `CoreComponent`, this Root Rounting Component will resolve any path you try to go to, but he can resolve part of it and send it to "Child Route Components" to handle/render the rest of the path. By doing `'...'` you delegate the rest of the rendering to another component that has `@RouteConfig` on it.

Comment: So if you do something like: '/somewhere/path1' you can have the core have `'/somewhere/...'` solving to a `SomewhereComponent`. `SomewhereComponent` would have a `@RouteConfig` that handles `/path1`, `/path2`, etc...

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll play around with it and see what happens! :) Great explanation, thanks.

Comment: Ok after I set it up like you said I came across a problem which I don't know how to resolve. How do you point to "Videos/list" for example if the route name of the parent route is only "Videos"? The parent route will never know which to resolve right?

Comment: I think it was somehting like this: `<a [routerLink]="['Videos','List']">`, not sure if that's your question.